# Use of current_date in Redshift materialised view

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I found in documentation that current_date function can't be used in materialised views, is there an alternative to this? I need current date in a filter condition within materialised view.

Thnx,

mc

Comment: This might be a limitation on incremental refreshes.  Can you do a full refresh?

Comment: Problem here is, it's not even allowing me to create the materialised view.